# Cannot mock GenericObjectPool class of Apache Commons with PowerMockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermockito

I have a requirement wherein I need to Mock creation of new GenericObjectPool object of Apache Commons Librabry.

Code to mock :

```
GenericObjectPool<Foo> objectPool = new GenericObjectPool<Foo>(Bar);
```

Mocking Bar object passed as the argument to constructor of GenericPoolObject works fine.

Code used to mock GenericObjectPool :

```
Bar mockBar = PowerMockito.mock(Bar.class);
GenericObjectPool<Foo> mockPool = PowerMockito.mock(GenericObjectPool.class);

PowerMockito.whenNew(Bar.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(mockBar);
PowerMockito.whenNew(GenericObjectPool.class).withArguments(mockBar).thenReturn(mockPool);

PowerMockito.when(mockPool.borrowObject()).thenReturn(dummyObject);
```

In @PrepareForTest, have included the class where new object of GenericObjectPool is created.
However i am not getting the mocked object, it always returns new GenericObjectPool() instance.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by moving the code of Mocking into individual test methods. Earlier I was doing the mocking in setUp method with @BeforeClass annotation.